# Value of ng-model getting changed when we change value for particular record

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I am populating my response from REST API using AngularJS on the front end by using ng-repeat . I'm Providing user with an option to modify each result that is displayed on the screen . When the User Modifies the value  for a Particular employee (lets say he is changing a dropdown )the same is getting reflected on HTML for other employee when clicking on modify record link of that employee . What should i do so that the details that are in the search response is being displayed in the HTML . This is my Search Response

```
var searchresponse = [{
"items": [{
    "employeeId": "ABC",
    "type": "D",
    "alive": "Yes"

}, {
    "employeeId": "DEF",
    "type": "D",
    "alive": "Yes"

}, {
    "employeeId": "NPK",
    "type": "D",
    "alive": "Yes"

}, {
    "employeeId": "PKN",
    "type": "D",
    "alive": "Yes"
}],
"more": false
}];
```

Controller Code by which I'm setting the results to search response

```
$http.post('http://localhost:8080/services/employee/search/'+Systems+"", searchCriteria)
.then(function(response) {

    $scope.searchresponse= [];
    $scope.searchresponse = response.data.items;
}
```

This is how i display the values on the Result page as a List.

```
<tr ng-repeat="details in searchresponse">
<td class=list align=center ng-switch="details.type">
<span
ng-switch-when="D">SINGLE</span><span
ng-switch-when="E">MULTIPLE</span>
</td>
```

Lets say i change the Value from D to E for employee ABC . When i click on the modify link for the employee PKN it is getting loaded with the dropdown selected as E .Why the changes i make for particular employee is getting reflected to the other employee.

This is my function which is used to load values for the HTML . Inside the HTML i have declared them as ng-model

```
$scope.ModifyEmployeeConfig = function(details ){
$scope.type= "" ;
$scope.type=  details.type; // I tried printing the value and see here the value in response only getting printed
}
```

This is my HTML

```
        <select name="type" class="pulldown1" id="type" ng-model="type">
        <option value="D">Single</option><option value="E">Multiple</option>
        </select>
```

Comment: Change `<tr ng-repeat="details in searchresponse">` to `<tr ng-repeat="items in searchresponse">` provided you are doing `$scope.searchresponse = searchresponse` in your controller

Comment: I tried it  , it didnt work . I am assigning response like this $scope.searchresponse = response.data.items;

Comment: You can paste your controller code so that we can point what is wrong. I suggest print the response.data somewhere.

Comment: Have updated the question

Comment: What i'm trying to do is . I'm displaying my results using ng-repeat on a single page with a hyperlink to modify . When user clicks on modify new page shows up with the data that is displayed on results page. when i changes the value from D to E here (modify page) . It is getting reflected to other records also when i click on their modify link .The scope variable lies the same. only the HTML is getting changed

Comment: If it is not to much I may suggest you ti create a plnkr.

Comment: Shouldn't it be ng-repeat="details in searchresponse.items"?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, it looks like you're changing the type variable, rather than the details.type variable in the dropdown. What you want to do is keep your dropdown inside the ng-repeat. Then you won't need to have a ModifyEmployeeConfig function at all.

If you want, you can only show the dropdown when a user clicks on a "Modify" button.

Something like this:

```
<tr ng-repeat="details in searchresponse">
    <td class="list" align="center" ng-switch="details.type">
        <span ng-switch-when="D">SINGLE</span>
        <span ng-switch-when="E">MULTIPLE</span>

        <button ng-if="!details.modify" ng-init="details.modify = false" ng-click="details.modify = true">Modify</button>

        <select ng-if="details.modify" class="pulldown1" id="type" ng-model="details.type">
            <option value="D">Single</option>
            <option value="E">Multiple</option>
        </select>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Point is, you have to make sure you're setting the type only on the details object that you are modifying, and not on a global type variable.

Comment: What i'm trying to do is . I'm displaying my results using ng-repeat on a single page  with a hyperlink to modify . When user clicks on modify new page shows up with the data that is displayed on results page. when i changes the value from D to E here (modify page) . It is getting reflected to other records also when i click on their modify link .The scope variable lies the same. only the HTML is getting changed

Comment: So where is the ModifyEmployeeConfig function called then?

Comment: it is getting called from the Result page html . The modify function and search function which makes API call are under same controller

Comment: So, it sounds like you just need to reset $scope.type on the modify page when the user clicks on the modify link. Looks like after you set it the first time, you don't reset it. 

It would be most helpful I think if you post the results page controller, view and modify page controller and view code. Otherwise your question is a bit confusing.

Comment: can you say me how to reset the scope.type value. yeah sure i will do that. Let me try resetting the value first

Comment: I'm afraid I can't really tell you until you publish all your code (a plunkr would help a lot!). Otherwise it's hard for me to know what goes where.

Comment: I have updated the question with more code here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41472767/change-in-ng-model-value-getting-changed-in-the-other-parts-of-the-list-also